# Extract the data from array using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
{
 "msg": ["Started arguments", "Completed"], 
 "code": [2, 4], 
 "time_stamp": ["14-12-20 10:15:25 am", "14-12-20 10:37:10 am"]
 }
```

I want to loop over and get the result like the following:

```
Message: Started arguments  
Status Code: 2 
Time: 14-12-20 10:15:25 am

Message: Completed
Status Code: 4
Time: 14-12-20 10:37:10 am
```

I have tried too may attempts but failed to extract the required result.

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: It should just be a simple `for` loop. `for (var i = 0; i < obj.msg.length; i++) ...`

Comment: then use `i` as an index into each of the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```js
const data = {
  "msg": ["Started arguments", "Completed"],
  "code": [2, 4],
  "time_stamp": ["14-12-20 10:15:25 am", "14-12-20 10:37:10 am"]
};

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.time_stamp.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    "msg": data.msg[i],
    "code": data.code[i],
    "time_stamp": data.time_stamp[i]
  });
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should check, if the length of all Arrays is the same, to be sure, nothing goes wrong... ;-)